# How can I make `react-beautiful-dnd` not trigger a `react-transition-group` animation?

Tags: css, reactjs, animation, react-transition-group, react-beautiful-dnd

Video demonstrating my issue: https://i.imgur.com/L3laZLc.mp4

I have a simple app where you can add Cards to 2 different Rows. When a card is added to a row, I'm using `react-transition-group` to trigger an "enter" animation.

However, I also have `react-beautiful-dnd` installed to enable dragging Cards between the Rows, and also to re-order the Rows themselves. But when a Card is moved to a new Row, or when the Rows are re-ordered, some of the cards have their "enter" animation fire, which looks very weird and should not be happening.

When dragging, the unwanted animation will fire when

1. A Card is dragged to a different Row.
2. A Row is re-ordered and the 2 Rows have different numbers of
   Cards.

Oddly, the unwanted animations will **not** happen when

1. A Card is dragged to a new position within its original Row.
2. The Rows are re-ordered and the Rows have the same number of Cards.

I would like to know how I can have it so the `react-transition-group` animations will not fire when the `state` is modified by using `react-beautiful-dnd`.

Sandbox of my issue (More information in comments in the `App.js` file):

https://codesandbox.io/s/get-beautiful-drag-to-not-trigger-transition-group-tc40w?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have modified solution by RaviNila to remove afforementioned blink when you drag between rows, by intoducing additional collection of styles. That blink was caused by this css property:

```
transition: all 200ms ease-out;
```

When item was rendered as a part of TransitionGroup even though it was set to timeout 0 and "" as a class, the transition still happend, propbably because newCardItem was changes in setTimeout. But removing setTimeout completely kills the animation. So repeating the styles without that transition property fully fixes your issue, afaics.

https://codesandbox.io/s/get-beautiful-drag-to-not-trigger-transition-group-share-bpc43

Comment: I am pleased that your solution solves the blinking issue, though I'm wondering if you can explain why you used `setImmediate()` on line 75? `setImmediate` is non-standard according to MDN, and they recommend not using in production, which my complete app intends to do.

Comment: you can change it to setTimeout, it was just something I've been experimenting with and not important to your issue

Comment: Thank you for helping solve this issue for me! I have awarded you the bounty :)

Answer (score 2):

In `App.js` you have mentioned the following comment which is your requirement:

---

**What I want:**

1. I would like the `react-transition-group` animations to fire only when new state is added
2. and not when state is modified by dragging and dropping (with the `onDragEnd` function);

---

This issue can be fixed just by introducing a new flag `hasNewCard`. This flag will be `true` only when a new card is created, not when state is modified by `onDragEnd`.

So here `react-transition-group` animation should fire only when `hasNewCard` is `true`.

CodeSandbox version:

https://codesandbox.io/s/get-beautiful-drag-to-not-trigger-transition-group-share-o25ej

Comment: In your version there is a blink in the row from which item has been dragged from.

Comment: Blink happens because of the dynamic size variation. if all the items are same size  it wont probably happen.

Comment: It does happen if it is same item in each row, dragged around. Even more, you can add just one item to any row and drag it around, it will blink in the previous row each time

Comment: I wish I could split the bounty, but since @PompolutZ was able to fix the flickering issue, I had to give it to him. I really appreciate your initial help.